# how do I call useHistory function in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import {Switch, Route, Redirect, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import  {DashboardPage}  from './pages/Dashboard';
import {Sidebar} from './components/Sidebar'
import {Menu} from './components/Menu'
import { guilds } from './utils/mocks';

function App() {
  const history = useHistory;
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar guilds={guilds} />
      <Menu history={history} />
      <Switch>
        <Redirect path='/' exact={true} to="/dashboard" />
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact={true} component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:guildId" exact={true} component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:guildId/general/muted" exact={true} component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard/:guildId/security/roles" exact={true} component={DashboardPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Type '<HistoryLocationState = unknown>() => History' is missing the following properties from type 'History': action, location, push, replace, and 6 more.  TS2740

```
11 |     <div>
12 |       <Sidebar guilds={guilds} />
13 |       <Menu history={history} />
   |                     ^
14 |       <Switch>
15 |         <Redirect path='/' exact={true} to="/dashboard" />
16 |         <Route path="/dashboard" exact={true} component={DashboardPage} />
```

> Do you mean to call the function?

This was the error I got in the code

Answer (score 0):

To execute (call, invoke) a function in javascript you need to use a pair of parenthesis after its name.

```
function someFunctionA() {
 // implementation 
}

const someOtherFunctionB = function() { // implementation } 
// callsite

someFunctionA();
someOtherFunctionB();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `useHistory()` is a hook and should be called as follows:

```js
const history = useHistory();
```

**not**

```js
const history = useHistory;
```

Let me know if it works.